# delimiters check using stack

Tags: java, stack, delimiter

the code checks if delimiters are balanced in the string or not. I've been using a stack to solve this. I traverse the string to the end, whenever an opening delimiter is encountered I push it into the stack, for each closing delimiter encountered I make a check if the stack is empty (and report error if it is) and then pop the stack to match the popped character and the closing delimiter encountered. I ignore all other characters in the string.
At the end of the traversal I make a check if the stack is empty (that is I check if all the opening delimiters were balanced out or not). If it's not empty, I report an error.
Although I have cross checked many times the code seems to be reporting every string as invaalid(i.e with unbalanced delimiters). Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class delimiter {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1 = "()";
        String s2 = "[}[]";
        if(delimitercheck(s1)){
            System.out.println("s1 is a nice text!");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("S1 is not nice");
        if(delimitercheck(s2)){
            System.out.println("s2 is a nice text!");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("S2 is not nice");
    }
    public static boolean delimitercheck(String s){
        Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<Character>();
        if(s==null||s.length()==0)//if it's a null string return true
            return true;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='('||s.charAt(i)=='{'||s.charAt(i)=='['){
                stk.push(s.charAt(i));
            }
            if(s.charAt(i)==')'||s.charAt(i)=='}'||s.charAt(i)==']'){
                if(stk.isEmpty()){
                    return false;
                }
                if(stk.peek()==s.charAt(i)){
                    stk.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        if(stk.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point to me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here :

```
            if(stk.peek()==s.charAt(i)){
                stk.pop();
            }
```

The `i`'th character shouldn't be equal to `stk.peek()`. It should be closing it. i.e. if `stk.peek() == '{'`, `s.charAt(i)` should be `'}'`, and so on.

In addition, if the current closing parenthesis doesn't match to top of the stack, you should return false.

You can either have a separate condition for each type of paretheses, or you can create a `Map<Character,Character>` that maps each opening parenthesis to its corresponding closing parenthesis, and then your condition will become :

```
            if(map.get(stk.peek())==s.charAt(i)){
                stk.pop();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

where `map` can be initialized to :

```
Map<Character,Character> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('(',')');
map.put('{','}');
map.put('[',']');
```

Comment: While what you say is true I believe that he should `return false` when that condition isn't met.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when encountering a closing bracket, you check if it is similar to the opening bracket which is not correct.

```
if(stk.peek()==s.charAt(i)){
    stk.pop();
}
```

should be replaced with something similar to

```
Character toCheck = s.charAt(i);
Character peek = stk.peek();

if (toCheck == ')') {
    if (peek == '(') {
        stk.pop();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else if ( // ... check all three bracket types
```

And *please* stick to brackets for *every* `if`-statement - there's nothing more tedious then one day encountering an error due to omitted brackets which will cause you more internal pain.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the stack value which has an opening delimiter with a closing delimiter. So for the first example you are checking '(' with ')'. Instead for every corresponding end delimiter you should check the stack for its starting delimiter i.e., '('  with  ')'. Hope that makes sense.